# Joining W2008 domain from PC on different subnet

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to join a W2008 AD domain from a pc on a different subnet. Subnet is configured as vlan on cisco switches with a router for traffic between vlans:

DC: 192.168.12.104 / PC: 192.168.13.11 / VLAN ROUTER: 192.168.12.2

Static routing on DC:

> Network Destination | Netmask | Gateway | Interface | Metric
>
> 192.168.13.0 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.12.2 | 192.168.12.104 | 21

I can ping **DC->PC** and **PC->DC**. If I enter the DC's IP, I can browse shares from the PC.
PC has DC as DNS server and is able to resolve hosts based on that.

**lmhosts** contents on PC:

> 192.168.12.104     org-server              #PRE #DOM:orgmi

The actual domain is "orgmi.local" but when I joined all the other PCs (on the same subnet as the DC) I just entered "orgmi".
Also, this is the only computer on another subnet that has to be on the domain. I have not set up any subnets/sites other than the main one in AD.

The error I'm getting contains this string "The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.orgmi"

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the mistake was made by installing first the DNS server and after the AD controller.
All the entries (listed in Nelogon.dns) for the domain name had not been imported in the zone so the computer couldn't find the proper DC.

Other PCs could find it via netbios being on the same VLAN.